# Spatial gradients as gradients in Lie algebras se(3) Tangent Space

Tags: linear-algebra, lie-groups, vector-analysis, lie-algebras, problem-solving

I am new to the topic of Lie groups and Lie algebra, and have been studying them a lot in the last couple days.
I am particularly interest in the $SE(3)$ Lie groups and $se(3)$ lie algebra as I am looking for ways to describe rigid body motions in an optimization problem.

My specific questions now is:
Given a function $f(\pmb{x}^o): \mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R} $ and each points local spatial gradient $\nabla f \bigg|_{\pmb{x}^o}$, (the reference frame points are given in is denoted with supscript $^o$), I am looking for the derivative of this function after the $se(3)$ twist coordinates $\tau_c^o \in \mathbb{R}^6$ so that $\hat{\tau_c^o} \in se(3)$, describing the lie group element $\mathcal{M}_c^o \in SE(3)$ transforming points between two frames ($\mathcal{M}_c^o \pmb{x}^c = \pmb{x}^o$) in the tangent space of the identity. So far I have:
$$\frac{\partial f(\pmb{x}^o)}{\partial \tau_c^o}  = \frac{\partial f(\pmb{x}^o)}{\partial \pmb{x}^o}\frac{\partial \pmb{x}^o}{\partial \tau_c^o}= \nabla f \bigg|_{\pmb{x}^o} \frac{\partial \pmb{x}^o}{\partial \tau_c^o}$$
Now with the exponential map $\exp(\hat{\tau_c^o})$ that maps the twist coordinates to $SE(3)$, the point $\pmb{x}^o$ can be expressed as $\pmb{x}^o =  \mathcal{M}_c^o \pmb{x}^c = \exp(\hat{\tau_c^o} ) \pmb{x}^c$ :
$$ \frac{\partial \pmb{x}^o}{\partial \tau_c^o} = \frac{\partial( \exp(\hat{\tau_c^o} ) \pmb{x}^c)}{\partial \tau_c^o} = \frac{\partial \exp(\hat{\tau_c^o})}{\partial \tau_c^o} \bigg|_{\tau_c^o}\pmb{x}^c = \frac{\partial \exp(\hat{\delta \tau})}{\partial (\delta \tau)} \bigg|_{\delta \tau = 0} \exp(\hat{\tau_c^o}) \pmb{x}^c = \frac{\partial \exp(\hat{\delta \tau})}{\partial (\delta \tau)} \bigg|_{\delta \tau = 0} \pmb{x}^o $$
From here [[1]](https://ethaneade.com/lie.pdf) I found that this equals a left hand side multiplication with the infinitessimal generators of $SE(3)$:
$$\frac{\partial \pmb{x}^o}{\partial \tau_c^o} = [G_1\pmb{x}^o, G_2\pmb{x}^o, G_3\pmb{x}^o, G_4\pmb{x}^o, G_5\pmb{x}^o, G_6\pmb{x}^o] = (I \mid (-\pmb{x}^o)_\times )$$
where $(.)_\times$ denotes the screw matrix and $I$ the identity matrix. Putting it all together this would give the following result:
$$ \frac{\partial f(\pmb{x}^o)}{\partial \tau_c^o}  = (\nabla f)^T \bigg|_{\pmb{x}^o} (I \mid (-\pmb{x}^o)_\times ) $$
Is this the correct result? does the left hand side multiplication with the infinitessimal generators really work like this? How does this result describe the correct derivative in the tangent space, when the spatial gradient given in the specific coordinate frame is just (partly) multiplied with the identity?

Basically I am looking for, what is the correct way to express a spatial gradient given in a specific coordinate reference frame, as a gradient in the $se(3)$ tangent space.

I welcome any kind of feedback.
Thank you.

Comment: Could you try describing what you are trying to do some more/in a different way? You start with a function on $\mathbb{R}^3$ (which means that there is a coordinate frame in space with makes it into $\mathbb{R}^3$). Then you have a twist $\tau$, which is an element of $se(3)$ represented as a vector in $\mathbb{R}^6$, the identification of $se(3)$ with $\mathbb{R}^6$ coming from the spatial frame. Now what? Do you want to perform the $\exp(\tau)$ motion and compute $\nabla (f \cdot \tau)$? Or what? Or do you have some function that depends on $\tau$? What are we taking the gradient of?

Comment: Also, your reference is 25 pages long and has 240 numbered formulas. Which computation in it are you referring to?